# I have a piece of homework due in on describing with adjectives and we just recently learned about prepositions which I'm unsure of, also grammar

Tags: grammar, usage, writing-critique

(this is all about my ideal bedroom and what I would like in it)

你好！我喜欢城市和雨天所以我想住在下雨的城市。我理想的卧室会很高也大。我的卧室有里很多窗。我想两张桌子在卧室里，也两张很小黄色的灯在桌子上。我的床是橙色的和很大。卧室里有很大电视 和电脑在桌子上。卧室不有椅子。然而，我喜欢我的卧室。

What I'm trying to write: Hello! I like cities and rainy days so I would like to live in a rainy city. My ideal bedroom would be big and tall. My bedroom would have lots of windows. I want 2 tables (desks) inside my bedroom and 2 yellow lamps on the tables. My bed would be orange and big. The bedroom would have a big TV and computer on a table. The bedroom will not have a chair. However, I like my bedroom the way it is.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some slight correcting:
我想两张桌子在卧室里，也两张很小黄色的等在桌子上-> 我希望卧室里有两张桌子，桌子上有两盏小黄灯；
卧室里有很大电视和电脑在桌子上 -> 卧室桌子上有大电视和电脑。
卧室不有椅子 -> 卧室没有椅子；

Correcting more like a native speaker:
大家好！我喜欢城市，也喜欢下雨天，所以我希望能住在一个多雨的城市。我理想的卧室应该很高很宽敞，并有很多窗户。在卧室里，我希望有两个桌子，桌子上有两个小黄台灯，大电视和电脑。卧室里还应该有一个橙色的大床，并且没有椅子。我喜欢这样的卧室。

If you need, I can also give you a more native version with a significant change, but i think it beyond your requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much! Please can you explain why certain changes have been made in the slight correcting paragraph? Thanks again!

Comment: @tva_learner Sure! For the first correction, there are two points: 1, 我希望 is similar with "I hope/wish" whereas 我想 is similar with "I think". So here "我希望" is better. 2, In Chinese, prepositional phrases are usually place before the corresponding object rather 
 than after as in English. So, 在卧室里&在桌子上here should be before 两张桌子&两盏小黄灯, respectively. 3, This sentence lacks the verb. It feels like: I think two desks in the bedroom, and two yellow lamps on the desks. So I add two "有" here. The second sentence has the same reasons.

Comment: @tva_learner The third sentence: if you want to say "have no ... ", most of the scenarios should use 没有。In addition, 不有 is a little weird in Mandarin and seems like a wrong word.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try smooth the writing:

我(**很**)喜欢城市**生活**和**下**雨天所以我想住在**多**雨的城市。我理想的卧室**要即**高**且**大, **還**有很多**的**窗**戶**。卧室里我想**放**两张桌子，**每**张桌子上**有盞**黃色的**小檯燈**。我的床是橙色的, **床很大**。卧室里**還**有**一個大型**电视和**一個桌上型**电脑。卧室**里可䏻放不下沙發椅, 但是我還是**喜欢我的卧室。

Answer (score 0):

你好！我喜欢在城市里享受下雨的天气，所以我想住在多雨的城市。我想象中的卧室十分宽敞，四周有许多窗户。我想在卧室里摆放两张桌子，桌子上布置两盏小黄灯，然后电脑放在桌子上。中间摆放一张橙色大床，床对面是一个大电视, 卧室周围布置一些椅子(方便就坐)。因此，我喜欢这样的卧室。